# Update weight through sql query

Tags: sql

I have created tons of products without setting the weight. Now I would like to add the weight, same weight to all products. Can a sql query help me? Is there some other solution.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look @ [How to update product weight and Country of Manufacture using mysql query in Magento 1.7.0.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142361/how-to-update-product-weight-and-country-of-manufacture-using-mysql-query-in-mag)

```
#1. First get weight attribute_id value (assume 80)
SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'weight';

#2. To view all products weight attribute to see if they all are empty
#SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal where attribute_id = 80;

#3. To update with new weight
Update catalog_product_entity_decimal as cped 
   set cped.value = [your new weight here] 
   where attribute_id = 80; # <- replace 80 with attribute_id from eav_attribute
```

*Always back-up your database before making major changes*

You could combine sql statement 1 and 3 see [mysql update join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/mysql-update-join)

```
Update catalog_product_entity_decimal cped
   join eav_attribute ev ON ev.attribute_id = cped.attribute_id 
   Set cped.value = 1 #<- change to your weight
   where ev.attribute_code = 'weight';
```

Comment: when migrating from an old mage1x that used grams in the DB: 
Update catalog_product_entity_decimal as cped 
   set cped.value = cped.value / 1000
   where attribute_id = 80;